# Ant - Poll REST resource to monitor remote process

Tags: ant

I'm a little bit of an Ant n00b, but I hope this question isn't too n00bish:

I have a section of an Ant script that needs to monitor a remote process and report whether it has succeeded or failed. The remote information is exposed as a REST resource. The process behind it may take several minutes, so I will likely need to poll several times before I get a result other than "in progress".

In very rough pseudo-code, I need something like this:

```
while(true) {
  get REST resource status
  if status='success' or status='failure'
    break;
  sleep 10
}
```

I know that I can (ab)use the `<waitfor>` task to repeatedly evaluate a condition, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that condition should be. The best I can come up with is to use a `<scriptcondition>`, but then I'm faced with the problem that Rhino JS (which Ant uses) has no `XMLHttpRequest` to send the REST query.

In other parts of the Ant script, we're using `<exec>` to run curl commands to interact with the REST service, but I don't see how to do that within the `<waitfor>`.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I'm stuck (for the time being) with Ant 1.7.1. Also, I realize it might be easier to push this to an external (bash, python, php, whatever) script, but I would prefer to keep it in the Ant script.